# JavaScript: How to bind a method?

Tags: javascript, oop

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/M2ALY/3/

My goal is to make a module that I can use and distribute. Therefore I must not pollute the global namespace. The module I'm making is also going to be used multiple times on one web page. That's why I chose to use OOP, but this introduced a problem.

I want my object to bind a function to be run when the user clicks an element in the DOM. In this simplified example I made, I want an alert box to pop up when the user clicks a paragraph. As an example, one of the things I need in the real project I'm working on is: The user clicks a canvas, the function figures out where the user clicked and saves it to this.clientX and this.clientY.

Instead of doing

```
this.bind = function() {
    $("p1").bind('click', function() {
        // code here
    });
}
```

I figured it would work if I did:

```
this.bind = function() {obj.codeMovedToThisMethod()}
```

The problem is that this isn't a good design. Inside the "class" you shouldn't need to know the name of the object(s) that is going to be made of this "class". This doesn't get better when I'm making multiple objects of the "class"...

So I figured I could do

```
$("p1").bind('click', function(this) {
        // code here
    });
}
```

But it didn't work because sending this into the function didn't work as I thought.

How should I solve this problem?
Here is a simplified sample problem. (Same as JSFiddle.)

```
var test = function() {
    this.alert = function() {
        alert("Hi");
    }

    this.bind = function() {
        $("#p1").bind('click', function() {
            obj.alert();
        });
    }        
}

window.obj = new test();
obj.bind();

// What if I want to do this:

var test2 = function() {
    // Private vars
    this.variable = "This secret is hidden.";

    this.alert = function() {
        alert(this.variable);
    }

    this.bind = function() {
        $("#p2").bind('click', function(this) {
            obj2.alert();
            this.alert();
        });
    }        
}

window.obj2 = new test2();
obj2.bind();​
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read [MDN's introduction to the `this` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this). As it's a keyword, you can't use it as a parameter name.

Use either

```
this.bind = function() {
    var that = this;
    $("#p2").on('click', function(e) {
        that.alert();
        // "this" is the DOM element (event target)
    });
}
```

or [`$.proxy`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/), the jQuery cross-browser equivalent to the [`bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) function:

```
this.bind = function() {
    $("#p2").on('click', $.proxy(function(e) {
        this.alert();
    }, this));
}
```

Comment: Do you know how jQuery does this?

Comment: Yes, `proxy` is the jQuery workaround (or lets say "facade") for the native [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) functionality, which creates a function with a pre-defined context object

Comment: Aha, so the proxy is throwing in the object as a parameter?

Comment: I think the [section on bound functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#Bound_functions) explains it quite well. Yet, I would not really recommend to use it because it's unusual (and therefore confusing), everyone expects `this` to be the event target in an event handler.

Comment: But why does this work? We use this as an argument in the .proxy method, don't we?

Comment: And you wrote that it's a cross-browser .bind(). So I did .bind (http://jsfiddle.net/M2ALY/5/) instead of using your $.proxy. Again, it worked. But how can you pass this as an argument in the bind() and not in my own function()?

Comment: `.bind()` creates a new function that calls the `function(e){ this.alert(); }` in the context given to it as the first argument. Here, we pass in the `this` of the bind method of the test object, i.e. the object itself.

Comment: Yes, I read a bit about it. But isn't `this` an argument in the `.bind()` method just as it is in my anonymous function?